# Retrieve Components Required by Workflow Process

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I have been trying to retrieve the list of "required components" of a specific Workflow process using the CRM SDK.  I can retrieve the desired workflow entity, but the required components are not referenced in that object to my knowledge.

Using that same id with a `RetrieveRequiredComponentsRequest` does run, but it returns an `EntityCollection` with 0 records as a result.  That is totally incorrect as there actually are required components.

```cs
Guid workflowId = WORKFLOW_GUID;
RetrieveRequiredComponentsRequest request = new RetrieveRequiredComponentsRequest();
request.ObjectId = workflowId; // confirmed correct id as the correct entity can be retrieved
RetrieveRequiredComponentsResponse response = (RetrieveRequiredComponentsResponse)service.Execute(request);
EntityCollection results = (EntityCollection)response.Results["EntityCollection"]; // the only key in Results was "EntityCollection"
foreach (var item in results.Entities) // okay, then what are their names?
{    
    Console.WriteLine("LogicalName: {0}", item.LogicalName); // prints nothing at all! wat?
}
Console.WriteLine("Results count: {0}", results.Entities.Count); // is 0...
```

I am confused because I *know* I have the ID for the workflow as I can properly fetch it with `service.Retrieve`.  Is `RetrieveRequiredComponents[Request|Response]` **not** the right thing to use to get workflow process dependencies?  It certainly works for other CRM objects.

EDIT(for part of the reason why the above code is wrong): `RetrieveRequiredComponents` looks for **solution** components such as entities, option sets, and web resources, not individual attributes of a solution component like fields of an entity.  That explains why I don't get my desired results, but it does not explain why the request yields no results at all.  I expect a couple entities to be returned.

Comment: Are you using the id of a specific instance of a workflow that has run, or the definition of the workflow itself?

Comment: The id I am using is for the workflow definition.  There were other ones, but they did not have the full workflow details.